# Select related object based on priority field

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic, where

I have two sobjects  `PriorityCase__c` (`Person__c`(master-detail to `Person__c`), `Priority__c`) and `Person__c` (name). And I want to select `Person__c` with the highest `Priority__c`. The highest priority is 1. So if `Person__c` related to a case with priority 1 it's the right result. If there are no `Person__c` with 1 priority check for 2 priority and so on.
So I have only that soql and don't know what to do.

```
SELECT Id,Name
        FROM Person__c
        WHERE Id IN (SELECT Person__c FROM PriorityCase__c WHERE ??)
```

Answer (score 0):

If Priority is a number value, it's easiest to build a Roll-up Summary field on `Person__c` to get the `MIN` value of the `Priority__c`, then you can just run a query on Person__c using the summary field.